# avcodec_encode_video2 return -542398533 Generic error in an external library only with h264 encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, ffmpeg-php, android-ffmpeg

```
pAvframe = GetVideoFrame();

av_init_packet(&pkt);
/* encode the image */
ret = avcodec_encode_video2(pAvCodecCtx, &pkt, pAvframe, &got_packet); //return Generic error in external library
if (ret < 0) 
{
    char errbuf[128];
    const char *errbuf_ptr = errbuf;

    if (av_strerror(ret, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf)) < 0)
        errbuf_ptr = strerror(AVUNERROR(ret));
    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "%s\n", errbuf_ptr);

    _stprintf_s(szErr,MAX_PATH, _T("Error encoding video frame:: "));
    LOG_ENTRY_ERROR(E_FAIL,szErr);
}



if(ret >= 0)
{
    ret = WriteFrameToFile(&pAvCodecCtx->time_base, m_stVideoStream.pAVStream, &pkt);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);

    }
}
```

It always return - -542398533 "Generic error in an external library" only with h.264 encoder please provide solution if gop is zero it work some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the contents of pAvFrame? For example, what is the `pix_fmt`, `width` and `height`? `pix_fmt` should (depending on the build of x264, but I'm assuming a typical config here) be `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`. Assuming 4:2:0 chroma subsampling, sizes should be even numbers. Are the `data` pointers and `linesize`s 32-byte aligned?

Could you also provide some information on how you initialized the encoder, i.e. the code that calls `avcodec_open2()`, particularly which entries you set in the `AVCodecContext` before the call to `avcodec_open2()`, and all calls to `av_opt_set_*()`.

Comment: I tried to set av_opt_set with three option  av_opt_set(pAvCodecCtx->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
av_opt_set(pAvCodecCtx->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
av_opt_set(pAvCodecCtx->priv_data, "x264opts", "no-mbtree:sliced-threads:sync-lookahead=0", 0);  tune and x264opts did the work but i want to know what is it set

Comment: don't touch priv_data, you can av_opt_set() on pAvCodecCtx and it will do the right thing. What do you mean "I want to know what is it set"?

Comment: `av_opt_set(pAvCodecCtx->priv_data, "x264opts", "no-mbtree:sliced threads:sync-lookahead=0", 0);`  what is meaning of this method and i tried to pass only pAvCodecCtx than again avcodec_encode_video2 return   -542398533

Comment: I was wrong, you need priv_data if you use 0 as last argument in av_opt_set(), or you can call it on pAvCodecCtx but need to change the 0 into AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN, sorry about that.

Comment: Ronald sorry for disturb you but last question is it required only for h264 encoder and can i set all available option like   `av_opt_set(pAvCodecCtx->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);  av_opt_set(pAvCodecCtx->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);  av_opt_set(pAvCodecCtx->priv_data, "x264opts", "no-mbtree:sliced threads:sync-lookahead=0", 0); `   thnks alots

Comment: av_opt_set(ctx->priv_data, "name", val) is for private options, so those options that are codec-specific (e.g. https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libx264_8c_source.html#l00902 for x264). For generic options (like keyframe interval, bitrate), you need to av_opt_set(pAvCodecCtx, "name", value), where option_name is anything from https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavcodec_2options__table_8h-source.html